# how to check an index of array of pointers which has a certian value?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i am new at c++ and i'm trying to get hold of the concept of pointers and arrays so my problem is thati have a class called "reservation" where it keeps a waiting list for unconfermed reservations
and i have an array of pointers . My question is how to check if the reservation is 1 using the array of pointers?

let's say

```
reservation** wait[i] ; // my array of pointers
if (wait[i]==1) // does this mean that i am checking if the index value is one?
```

thank you so much for answering and i would like some further explanation on this topic if you are willing? =)

Comment: Your declaration of array of pointers is wrong !

Comment: I would expect an array of pointers declared like this: `int** my_array;`. There is no indexing involved there. If the number of pointers is known, you could declare it something like that: `int* my_array[n];`.

Answer (score 0):

first: `reservation** wait[i] ; // my array of pointers`
you better use capital letters for class names.
what you declared is an array of pointers to pointers to objects of class `reservation`
you have `i` as the length of the array, you can't use a variable for the length of the array.
it needs to be constant given at compile time

so what you should write is:

```
const int SIZE = 50; // change the value as you like
Reservation* wait[SIZE] ; // my array of pointers
```

now to check if the reservation at index i is available , there should be a member you access to give you that, something like:

```
    if (wait[i] -> isReserved()) // you can access field from a pointer using ->
                                  // assuming isReserved() is a member of reservation
                                 // that returns a boolean
```

showing your class `reservation` would be helpful